# Showing the properties of an isomorphism between finite dimensional vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$ \phi: V \rightarrow W  $ an isomorphism between finite-dimensional vector spaces. For a subspace $U$ of $V$  we can write

$ \phi(U):= {\{ \phi(u): u \in U} \} = \operatorname{im}( \phi | _{U})$

Show that:

I. $\dim (\phi(U))= \text{dim} (U) $

II. $ \dim(\phi^{-1}(X)) = \dim(X)  $

Comment: If $\dim V = n$ and $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ is a base for $V$, what do we know about $\phi(v_1),\dots, \phi(v_n)$?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get it

Comment: @Herrpeter Please provide some context for your question. Where did you come across this problem? What have you tried, and where are you running into trouble? Do you understand what it means for $\phi$ to be an "isomorphism" in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Apply the rank-nullity theorem to the linear map $\phi|_U : U \to \phi(U)$.

Answer (score 1):

**For the first one** : Try showing that $\phi | _{U}$ is a bijective linear map from $U$ to $\phi(U)$ (an isomorphism), conclude.
**For the second one** : as $\phi$ is bijective, $\phi(\phi^{-1}(X))$ = $X$, then use i for $U=X$.

Keep in mind that only $U$ and $X$ have to be finite dimensional, $V$ need not be finite dimensional for this proof to hold.

Answer (score 1):

I. $\phi$ is injective, so if $u_1,...,u_n$ is a basis for $U$, then $\phi(u_1),...,\phi(u_n)$ is a basis for $\phi(U)$.

II. The inverse of a bijective linear map is a bijective linear map, so we may use part I.